# Unable to get response from Parsley AJAX input value validator

Tags: jquery, ajax, parsley.js

I have a multistep form, where I use Parsley JS Validator for the entire form, this works lige it should, but in a certain field called "initials" I need to validate using an AJAX return to validate if the initials are available or not. The field validates fine on focusout on the pattern and length, but its like I am unable to trigger the AJAX and does not get any errors or feedback in Chrome Developer Console, so I am having a little difficult debugging it .. can anyone come with a clue to what is wrong here?

**The input "initials" field:**

```
<input class="maxLength form-control" type="text" name="initials" id="initials" data-parsley-pattern="^[a-zA-Z]+$" data-parsley-errors-container="#initials-errors" data-parsley-trigger="focusout" data-parsley-initials data-parsley-initials-message="Initials allready taken" maxlength="3" minlength="3" Required>
```

**Overall Parsley Form validation:**

```
    $('.form-navigation .next').click(function() {
        $('.demo-form').parsley().whenValidate({
            group: 'block-' + curIndex()
        }).done(function() {
            navigateTo(curIndex() + 1);
        });
    });
```

**Initials field Parsley validation:**

```
      $('#initials').parsley();
      
      window.Parsley.addValidator('checkinitials', {
        validateString: function(value)
        {
          return $.ajax({
            url:'check_initials_availability.asp',
            method:"POST",
            data:{initials:value},
            dataType:"json",
            success:function(data)
            {
              return true;
            }
          });
        }
```

Comment: have you tried ``window.Parsley.addValidator('initials',{`` only?

Comment: Hi @RohitMittal its the same result, meaning I get nothing in console, no data and no errors